# How to color a range of columns starting from row 3

Tags: vba

with the command I color all columns starting from the first row,

`Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Parent.Columns("A:I").Interior.ColorIndex = 42`

but I would need to color the columns from A to I starting from row 3, how can I set the command, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Columns` means entire column so you need to use `Range`, to color only a range. Also it is unclear what you want to do with `Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Parent` because this is the same as `ActiveSheet`.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:I1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 42
```

Here `3` is the first row and `1000` is the last row that gets colored in the columns `A` to `I`.